# Stack allocation, why the extra space?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, stack, memory-alignment

I was playing around a bit to get a better grip on calling conventions and how the stack is handled, but I can't figure out why main allocates three extra double words when setting up the stack (at `<main+0>`).  It's neither aligned to 8 bytes nor 16 bytes, so that's not why as far as I know.  As I see it, main requires 12 bytes for the two parameters to func and the return value.

What am I missing?

The program is C code compiled with "gcc -ggdb" on a x86 architecture.

Edit: I removed the -O0 flag from gcc, and it made no difference to the output.

```
(gdb) disas main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
    0x080483d1 <+0>:    sub    esp,0x18
    0x080483d4 <+3>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x4],0x7
    0x080483dc <+11>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x3
    0x080483e3 <+18>:   call   0x80483b4 <func>
    0x080483e8 <+23>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x14],eax
    0x080483ec <+27>:   add    esp,0x18
    0x080483ef <+30>:   ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

Edit: Of course I should have posted the C code:

```
int func(int a, int b) {
    int c = 9;
    return a + b + c;
}

void main() {
    int x;
    x = func(3, 7);
}
```

The platform is Arch Linux i686.

Comment: It might be helpful to post the C code

Comment: The platform would also be useful, since you are asking about calling conventions. Mac OS X's, for instance, requires the stack to be kept aligned on 16-bytes boundaries.

Comment: It's best to assume that when you disable optimizations that you'll end up looking at un-optimized code.

Comment: @HansPassant Certainly, but it makes no difference in this particular case. I recompiled without it, and the disassembly is identical.

Comment: Hmm, that can't be right.  You should only have `ret` left after optimization.  The code has no side effects so can be completely eliminated.

Comment: The default behaviour of gcc is no optimization, as in -O0, which is why it made no difference removing the flag.

You need to explicitly state that you want optimization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's alignment. I assumed for some reason that `esp` would be aligned from the start, which it clearly isn't.

`gcc` aligns stack frames to 16 bytes per default, which is what happened.

Comment: The stack is aligned by 16 *before* a `call` instruction, so the args are 16B-aligned.  IF the stack didn't have a known alignment before entry to `main`, gcc would emit code that used `and esp, -16` to align it.

Answer (score 5):

The parameters to a function (including, but not limited to `main`) are already on the stack when you enter the function. The space you allocate inside the function is for local variables. For functions with simple return types such as `int`, the return value will normally be in a register (`eax`, with a typical 32-bit compiler on x86).

If, for example, `main` was something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
   char a[35];

   return 0;
}
```

...we'd expect to see at least 35 bytes allocated on the stack as we entered main to make room for `a`. Assuming a 32-bit implementation, that would normally be rounded up to the next multiple of 4 (36, in this case) to maintain 32-bit alignment of the stack. We would not expect to see any space allocated for the return value. `argc` and `argv` would be on the stack, but they'd already be on the stack before `main` was entered, so `main` would not have to do anything to allocate space for them.

In the case above, after allocating space for `a`, `a` would typicaly start at `[esp-36]`, `argv` would be at `[esp-44]` and `argc` would be at `[esp-48]` (or those two might be reversed -- depending on whether arguments were pushed left to right or right to left). In case you're wondering why I skipped `[esp-40]`, that would be the return address.

Edit: Here's a diagram of the stack on entry to the function, and after setting up the stack frame:

[image]

Edit 2: Based on your updated question, what you have is slightly roundabout, but not particularly hard to understand. Upon entry to `main`, it's allocating space not only for the variables local to `main`, but also for the parameters you're passing to the function you call from `main`.

That accounts for at least some of the extra space being allocated (though not necessarily all of it).

Comment: But main() only has three local ints, 12 bytes.  So why does it allocate 24 bytes?

Comment: @spektre: The rest is padding, to align the stack to 16 bytes. Try modifying `func()` to use less/more arguments. You'll notice that `main()`'s stack area changes in 16-byte increases (with more arguments you'll eventually see `sub esp,0x28`, then with more arguments it will change to `sub esp,0x38`, ...).

Comment: @ninjalj
Alignment was the first thing I thought of, but it didn't add up as I assumed `esp` already was aligned when entering `main()`. Although now that I think about it, alignment would never be necessary if it was.

Why isn't it aligned from the start then? Surely the code running before entering `main()` uses the stack, or does that code strictly lie in another context or something?