# why is gcc allocating more space to char buffer

Tags: gcc, buffer-overflow

I am kind of confused by the latest version of gcc. A simple piece of code is compiled:

```
int main()
{
    char buffer[1];

    scanf("%s",buffer);

   printf("You Entered %s\n", buffer );
   return 0;
}
```

When I dissemble the func, this is what i find :

```
(gdb) disas main
Dump of assembler code for function main:

  0x0804846d <+0>:  push   %ebp
  0x0804846e <+1>:  mov    %esp,%ebp
  0x08048470 <+3>:  and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
  0x08048473 <+6>:  sub    $0x20,%esp
  0x08048476 <+9>:  lea    0x1f(%esp),%eax
  0x0804847a <+13>: mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
...........................
```

My question is why do we subtract 0x20 i.e 32 bytes, when I allocate just 1 byte ! I dont understand this strange behaviour

P.S. I was studying buffer overflows but this problem doesnt seem to be related to it,still fyi I had turned ASLR off and other gcc stack protection stuff.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stack allocation, why the extra space?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862017/stack-allocation-why-the-extra-space)

Comment: might be, well then it should be 16 bytes, isnt it ?

Comment: Requirements change depending on the ABI. What is your platform?

Comment: i686 GNU/Linux (3.13.0-24) - That is 32 bit as outlined in [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246007/how-to-determine-whether-a-given-linux-is-32-bit-or-64-bit]